# How to debug FUSE filesystem when it is running in daemon mode?

Tags: filesystems, driver, fuse

I am debugging a FUSE filesystem. It runs fine whenever I enable the `-d` or `-f` flag, but whenever I make it a daemon, it stops working (showing no files).

Is there a way for the daemon to print something to a log file? I have tried

```
-ologfile='./log'
```

but I just get an "unknown option" message.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to add a log function of your own would be in the code of this file system, using libfuse function `fuse_set_log_func`:

https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/fuse__log_8h.html#af19307887778edec299c02c1e858addd

To debug the file system as it is, in some implicit way, would be to `strace` the file operations you are calling *on* it. for instance, `strace ls /mnt/my_fuse` will at least show you errors if some system call fails. It might give you a clue what fuse function is failing on the fuse side of this call.